# asus tuf gaming x570 pro (wifi) cpu pin

Tags: cpu, motherboard, asus, pin

I just bought asus tuf gaming x570 pro (wi-fi) ant it has 8+4 cpu pin but my power supply has 8+8 pin. Will it work, if i put only 8 pin? Or just plug 8+8 to 8+4 pin

Comment: Some 8-pin connectors are splittable (4+4). Try it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 8-pin connectors should be splittable into 4+4. If space permits you can also partially insert a longer connector - just make sure the pins go in all the way.

If neither works you'll require an adapter.